# Contact Us page breaks after submitting the form

Tags: support, bug, contact

Recently, I reached Contact Us page regarding merging accounts.

However, when I fill all required details and submit the form, it says,

[image]

I have tried the same on Stack Overflow and Movies & TV and all result in the same error.

What's the issue here?

Comment: "We've got 90% fewer tickets last week. The people must be really satisfied"

Comment: @Magisch Well, I don't have any problem here ;-). This is about merging accounts.

Comment: I know, I was making a joke :D

Comment: Can you please upload a real size screenshot? What you have is unreadable, it's downsized for some reason.

Comment: @Sha just need to remove the "m" from the end of the image name

Comment: @ShadowWizard I added "m" at the end of the image URL, which apparently has been removed by Cai.

Comment: @AJ oh, didn't notice. In the future, if you do this, please link to the full size image, so that we can see it. I thought you uploaded small picture to begin with.

Comment: Its a pretty standard error message. That said, maybe email them?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek How? Via contact us page? It's broken. ;-)

Comment: .... I can never remember which one of the two emails we're aware of is public... ;p

Comment: The public email is `team@stackexchange.com` e.g. it's mentioned [here](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy). /cc @Journeyman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some clarifying information from a [chat transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43421838#43421838), what you are actually trying to do is merge **Data Explorer** accounts. Our contact us form simply doesn't work for those accounts. I'm not sure why it throws a server error with them, but it's very much by-design that you wouldn't be able to use that form to merge those accounts *anyways*, so the fix would just be a more graceful error message, which is probably not the goal you wanted to achieve here.

Data Explorer uses open source software and a completely different accounts system, which does not support having more than one credential on your account anyways. Logging in via a bunch of different ways will continue to create a bunch of different accounts for each different login method.

To be quite honest, you could *probably* get them merged by bugging a dev to merge them, assuming there's actually good reason for the merge (e.g. not a bunch of empty accounts that have never done anything). But merging SEDE accounts is not something we officially support, simply because with the way SEDE is built, it doesn't make much sense to support merging accounts there outright. Merging may move any queries you've created, but you'd still end up with one credential, and you'd still continue creating additional accounts by using other credentials. You'll just have to remember which one you used for Data Explorer and keep using it.

Comment: Oh. I should add those queries from another account in the favorite list and leave it as it is then. Thank you.